# How to JUnit test that my mocked method is called with the parameter i want (not just id, but deep equal matcher)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here is a part of my method that i want to test:

```
protected void myMethod(MyObject o) {
     o.setComment("comment");
     MyObjectDAO.updateMyObject(o);
}
```

Here is a part of my JUnit:

```
    @Mock
    private MyObjectDAO myObjectDaoMock;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
         MyObject o = new MyObject();

         // Run Test
         x.myMethod(o);

         // Control
         assertEquals("comment", o.getComment());
         verify(myObjectDaoMock).updateMyObject(o);
    }
```

The test is green; we are now testing whether the comment attribute of myObject is set, and the update method is called with myObject. But **not** whether the update method is called **with the updated attribute** (after setComment method). When we change the position of two lines in myMethod (first updating the object, then setting its attribute), our test is still green.

I thought that the ArgumentCaptor can be useful here. So i made this one:

```
    @Mock
    private MyObjectDAO myObjectDaoMock;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
         MyObject o = new MyObject();

         // Run Test
         x.myMethod(o);

         // Control
         ArgumentCaptor<MyObject> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyObject.class);
         verify(myObjectDaoMock).updateMyObject(argumentCaptor.capture());
         MyObject oActual = argumentCaptor.getValue();
         assertEquals("comment", oActual.getComment());
    }
```

... hoping that the ArgumentCaptor will capture that state of the object, by which the update method is called, so i can be sure that the update method is called with the updated comment attribute. The test is green again. **But it still does not test cleverly.** When we change the position of two lines in myMethod again (first updating the object, then setting its attribute), our test is still green.

I understand that, the ArgumentCaptor does not create another attribute for himself (argumentCaptor.getValue()), it is the reference of the original object. So since java works with **Reference by Value**, for JUnit it does not make any difference whether i update the object before or after, as long as the objectIds are same.

**How can i actually test that the updateObject method is called with the updated value of myObject?**

***EDIT:*** Another idea was (thanks to @Crazyjavahacking) to mock also myObject (although i don't want that), and define a call-order with 2 mocks:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(o, myObjectDAOMock);

inOrder.verify(o).setComment("comment");
inOrder.verify(myObjectDAOMock).updateMyObject(o);
```

That still does not test that the method is called with the updated value. It just test the order. When we change our code:

```
o.setComment("comment"); 
o.setComment("comment2"); 
MyObjectDAO.updateMyObject(o);
```

.. our test would still run green, since the order is correct based on our order definition. But the method is not called with the updated value "comment" as we want.

Comment: What if you were to extend `MyObject` just in this test and override its `equals` and `hashcode` to work exactly the way you want?  Would that work?

Comment: Our test classes already extend our abstract test classes... Even if they weren't, when there is not any other solution, i would prefer simply not to test those cases instead of extending test classes from domain objects..

Comment: OK then why isn't the comment already considered in the `equals` method?

Comment: From functional point of view, it should not. But from technical side, we still should cover this case with JUnit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is behaving differently because you are mixing 2 concepts:

1. mocking
2. assertions

The only way to do what you need is to have mocked both `MyObject` and `MyObjectDAO`. In that case you can verify whether the setter was called on `MyObject` and also the order of calls. In Mockit use the

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(o, myObjectDAOMock);

inOrder.verify(o).setComment("...");
// 1.) inOrder.verify(o, times(0)).setComment(anyString());
inOrder.verify(myObjectDAOMock).updateMyObject(o);

// 2.) assertEquals(o.getComment(), "comment");

// 3.) verifyNoMoreInteractions(o);
```

construction.

Couple of notes:

1. this will guaranteed there are no more other invocations to `setComment()`
2. if we will use `@Spy` for `MyObject` instead of `@Mock`, we can verify what is the final value of the comment in `MyObject` instance
3. this will guarantee no other invocation is performed on the passed instance

Comment: That still does not test that the method is called with the updated value. It just test the order. When we change our code:      

o.setComment("comment");
o.setComment("comment2");
MyObjectDAO.updateMyObject(o);

your test would still run green, since the order is correct based on your order definition. But the method is not called with the updated value "comment" as we want.. But it is a good try, or approach. Thank you.

Comment: That's correct, sorry I missed that point. You can easily achieve that by calling `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` method.

Comment: Almost :) Unfortunately it tests what we want, but again just in this case. In an indirect way so to speak..  So when i change my code so: o.setComment("comment"); 
o.getXXX();
MyObjectDAO.updateMyObject(o);  the test would run red, since we use the object again in between those two lines.. But actually the method is OK.. test should still run green..

Comment: Those are nice approaches actually, but not cleverly designed. Because we are always tyring to avoid those cases i write in "..if we change our code: ... ", instead of thinking a solution for the actual problem: "testing that the method is called with the intended value".

Comment: Even if when there was a verifyNoMoreInteractions method, which omits getters, -again we would still be trying to avoid those cases, so.. - o.setComment("comment"); o.setXXX(); MyObjectDAO.updateMyObject(o) where i just want to test whether comment is set, the test would be red, obwohl my method runs correctly..

Comment: You are right. Testing that the method is called with the intended value can only be modelled by defining what intended value is. If it is the comment and the only way to change it is by using setter, you have to explicitly say it to the Mockito. Try the latest code.

Comment: inOrder.verify(o).setComment("...");
inOrder.verify(o, times(0)).setComment(anyString());
inOrder.verify(myObjectDAOMock).updateMyObject(o);

I think those lines provides what i need.. Thank you!